# waitForDuration not working on some devices

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, skaction, performselector

I'm facing a very strange issue with waitForDuration.
This code works perfectly on my iPad mini, but doesn't work on my iPad mini 3.

```
SKAction * wait = [SKAction waitForDuration:1];
SKAction * fire = [SKAction preformSelector:@selector(fireNextButton) onTarget:self];
SKAction * sequence = [SKAction sequence:@[wait, fire]];
[self runAction:sequence];
```

On the mini 3, it calls the runAction, but the fireNextButton method is never called.
Is there any reason for that to happen??

Thank you!

Jeremy

Comment: could you show the fireNextButton's declaration ? is it the same for diff devices ?

Comment: Actually, I replaced the 2 actions with different actions and the 2nd action is never triggered on this device. So the SKAction.sequence is the problem.
I only have those 2 devices right now.

Comment: it seams weird as your code is correct, may be the "target" is destroyed somehow ?

Comment: How can it be destroyed? I have not done any code to purposely stop the action at least.

Answer (score 0):

Got it!
I had a float property named speed in my SKScene declaration and set it to 1.4 during initiation.
I renamed this property gameSpeed and everything works now.
Can somebody explain why it was causing a problem only on the iPad mini 3?
Both devices run the same iOS 8.1...